# SVG SMIL Animation not animating

Tags: javascript, svg, smil

I need to create an SVG animation of 2 steps, for that I tried with JS. It worked but the animation wasn't playing "correctly" let's say it just go from step a to step b without anything between.

After a few research I disabled my js to try to animate my elt with SMIL using from and to attributes.

which gives us that code:

```
<svg class="ronce-svg" id="Calque_1" data-name="Calque 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1165.1 826.09" style="transition: 0.5s ease;">
            <path id="ronces" d="M1031,443.55s-27.35-7.84-66.35-14.74l-3.93-47.72L938.8,424.68c-38.46-5.44-83.57-8.69-124.23-3.51l-26.31-47.09-7.33,53.76a145.32,145.32,0,0,0-36.48,15.48c-23.37,14.34-43.09,36.27-61.07,62.1l-47.11-12.05,32.25,34.76c-14.32,23.15-27.83,48.3-41.63,73.29L578,591.18l31.29,41.37c-17,29.13-35,56.76-56,79.31l-42.52-23.81L534,730.28q-5,4.2-10.22,8c-29.72,21.53-58.5,27.39-88.39,27.21L424.26,732.6l-18.1,31.15c-32.43-3.22-66.83-9.71-105.61-8.24l-16.65-27-10.49,29.35a269.93,269.93,0,0,0-69.1,19.35q-3.51,1.5-6.93,3.15l-25.64-21.1,5.61,32.64c-28.06,18.94-50.27,46.19-69.52,77.19L72.28,858.31l25.19,28.27c-14.65,25.84-27.74,53.56-40.77,80.79l-42.11-9.08,30.76,32.57c-18,36.79-36.82,71.39-60.18,97.69l-25.95-17.48,12,31.67c-13.43,12.16-28.36,21.65-45.38,27.55C-202.69,1174.87-84.39,1199-84.39,1199s6.61,2,18.35.77a90,90,0,0,0,15.77-3.15c3.31-1,6.84-2.17,10.55-3.66,27.87-11.2,66.64-38.81,110.09-104.5q2.85-4.29,5.72-8.82l53.6,12.33-36.28-41.3c21-37.17,37-68.42,50.9-94.67l30.62,8.69L156,934.11c10.42-19,19.92-34.91,30-48.16l32.3,11.45-20-26a122.9,122.9,0,0,1,40.53-28.58l22,23.92-3.41-30.73c21.53-6.46,48.21-10.24,82.92-12.3l6.58-.37L358,853.22l12.16-30.74c47.87-1.32,87.45.8,122.18-2.81L516,856.05l3.65-40.78c43.1-9.87,79.2-34.33,116.42-95l49.48,11.16-33.44-39.48q3.66-6.92,7.33-14.34c12.86-25.93,22.77-49.8,31.36-71.57l56-.42-42.28-34.89c10-25.45,19.36-47.26,31.75-65.38L787.9,525.5l-28.51-46.1c22-18.62,52.7-30.79,100.57-36.39l26.21,49.73L897,440.15C933.07,438.57,977,439.69,1031,443.55Z" 
                  transform="translate(134.07 -374.08);transition:0.5s ease"
            />
            <animate
                begin="0"
                xlink:href="#ronces"
                attributeName="d"
                attributeType="XML"
                from="M1031,443.55s-27.35-7.84-66.35-14.74l-3.93-47.72L938.8,424.68c-38.46-5.44-83.57-8.69-124.23-3.51l-26.31-47.09-7.33,53.76a145.32,145.32,0,0,0-36.48,15.48c-23.37,14.34-43.09,36.27-61.07,62.1l-47.11-12.05,32.25,34.76c-14.32,23.15-27.83,48.3-41.63,73.29L578,591.18l31.29,41.37c-17,29.13-35,56.76-56,79.31l-42.52-23.81L534,730.28q-5,4.2-10.22,8c-29.72,21.53-58.5,27.39-88.39,27.21L424.26,732.6l-18.1,31.15c-32.43-3.22-66.83-9.71-105.61-8.24l-16.65-27-10.49,29.35a269.93,269.93,0,0,0-69.1,19.35q-3.51,1.5-6.93,3.15l-25.64-21.1,5.61,32.64c-28.06,18.94-50.27,46.19-69.52,77.19L72.28,858.31l25.19,28.27c-14.65,25.84-27.74,53.56-40.77,80.79l-42.11-9.08,30.76,32.57c-18,36.79-36.82,71.39-60.18,97.69l-25.95-17.48,12,31.67c-13.43,12.16-28.36,21.65-45.38,27.55C-202.69,1174.87-84.39,1199-84.39,1199s6.61,2,18.35.77a90,90,0,0,0,15.77-3.15c3.31-1,6.84-2.17,10.55-3.66,27.87-11.2,66.64-38.81,110.09-104.5q2.85-4.29,5.72-8.82l53.6,12.33-36.28-41.3c21-37.17,37-68.42,50.9-94.67l30.62,8.69L156,934.11c10.42-19,19.92-34.91,30-48.16l32.3,11.45-20-26a122.9,122.9,0,0,1,40.53-28.58l22,23.92-3.41-30.73c21.53-6.46,48.21-10.24,82.92-12.3l6.58-.37L358,853.22l12.16-30.74c47.87-1.32,87.45.8,122.18-2.81L516,856.05l3.65-40.78c43.1-9.87,79.2-34.33,116.42-95l49.48,11.16-33.44-39.48q3.66-6.92,7.33-14.34c12.86-25.93,22.77-49.8,31.36-71.57l56-.42-42.28-34.89c10-25.45,19.36-47.26,31.75-65.38L787.9,525.5l-28.51-46.1c22-18.62,52.7-30.79,100.57-36.39l26.21,49.73L897,440.15C933.07,438.57,977,439.69,1031,443.55Z"
                to="M970.58,357.22s-2,28.38-8.85,67.39l43.5,20-48.47,5.71c-8,38-20.42,81.5-39.19,117.94l35.25,40.83-53-11.5a145,145,0,0,1-27,29c-21.47,17.06-48.81,28.09-79.24,36.16l-4.78,48.39-21.64-42.2c-26.65,5.54-54.9,9.63-83.11,14.06l-7.09,49.41-28.17-43.55c-33.17,6-65.31,13.47-93.68,25.51l7.82,48.1-31.74-36.25q-5.65,3.25-11,6.87c-30.39,20.57-45.74,45.61-55.8,73.75l27.09,21.69L456,834.88c-8.07,31.58-13.74,66.12-28.38,102.06l19.67,24.88-31.17-.19A269.7,269.7,0,0,1,374.27,1020c-1.74,1.86-3.51,3.68-5.32,5.44L380,1056.7l-28.75-16.44c-27.39,19.89-60.59,31.44-96.31,38.93l-2,37.09-18-33.34c-29.29,4.93-59.81,7.75-89.86,10.69l-5.87,42.67-20.08-40c-40.74,4.38-79.67,10.18-112.39,23.14l7.56,30.36-25.67-22.07c-16,8.46-30,19.24-41.41,33.22C-138.6,1266.4-120.81,1147-120.81,1147s.38-6.89,5.55-17.5a89.74,89.74,0,0,1,8.36-13.74,110.18,110.18,0,0,1,7-8.67c20.06-22.35,59.27-49.34,135.85-67.71q5-1.2,10.25-2.36L53,982.42l26.39,48.22c42.11-7,77-11.4,106.37-15.45l2.31-31.75,22.28,28.21c21.43-3.29,39.61-6.78,55.5-11.68l.28-34.27,17.55,27.72a123.08,123.08,0,0,0,40.71-28.32l-14.94-28.89,27.72,13.71c13.43-18,26.1-41.8,39.91-73.71q1.32-3,2.6-6.06l-24.26-20.58,33-.92c17.6-44.53,29.16-82.45,44.42-113.85l-26.07-34.71,39.57,10.52c24-37.12,59.34-62.69,129.12-76.89l6.43-50.32,25.67,44.92q7.75-1.05,16-2c28.77-3.21,54.58-4.36,78-5l19.56-52.51,18.33,51.66c27.34-.7,51-2,72.29-7.47l-1.33-55.38L844,600.2c25-14.29,47-39,68.59-82.05l-37.76-41.64,53.1,7.86C941.75,451,955.73,409.28,970.58,357.22Z"
                value="M1031,443.55s-27.35-7.84-66.35-14.74l-3.93-47.72L938.8,424.68c-38.46-5.44-83.57-8.69-124.23-3.51l-26.31-47.09-7.33,53.76a145.32,145.32,0,0,0-36.48,15.48c-23.37,14.34-43.09,36.27-61.07,62.1l-47.11-12.05,32.25,34.76c-14.32,23.15-27.83,48.3-41.63,73.29L578,591.18l31.29,41.37c-17,29.13-35,56.76-56,79.31l-42.52-23.81L534,730.28q-5,4.2-10.22,8c-29.72,21.53-58.5,27.39-88.39,27.21L424.26,732.6l-18.1,31.15c-32.43-3.22-66.83-9.71-105.61-8.24l-16.65-27-10.49,29.35a269.93,269.93,0,0,0-69.1,19.35q-3.51,1.5-6.93,3.15l-25.64-21.1,5.61,32.64c-28.06,18.94-50.27,46.19-69.52,77.19L72.28,858.31l25.19,28.27c-14.65,25.84-27.74,53.56-40.77,80.79l-42.11-9.08,30.76,32.57c-18,36.79-36.82,71.39-60.18,97.69l-25.95-17.48,12,31.67c-13.43,12.16-28.36,21.65-45.38,27.55C-202.69,1174.87-84.39,1199-84.39,1199s6.61,2,18.35.77a90,90,0,0,0,15.77-3.15c3.31-1,6.84-2.17,10.55-3.66,27.87-11.2,66.64-38.81,110.09-104.5q2.85-4.29,5.72-8.82l53.6,12.33-36.28-41.3c21-37.17,37-68.42,50.9-94.67l30.62,8.69L156,934.11c10.42-19,19.92-34.91,30-48.16l32.3,11.45-20-26a122.9,122.9,0,0,1,40.53-28.58l22,23.92-3.41-30.73c21.53-6.46,48.21-10.24,82.92-12.3l6.58-.37L358,853.22l12.16-30.74c47.87-1.32,87.45.8,122.18-2.81L516,856.05l3.65-40.78c43.1-9.87,79.2-34.33,116.42-95l49.48,11.16-33.44-39.48q3.66-6.92,7.33-14.34c12.86-25.93,22.77-49.8,31.36-71.57l56-.42-42.28-34.89c10-25.45,19.36-47.26,31.75-65.38L787.9,525.5l-28.51-46.1c22-18.62,52.7-30.79,100.57-36.39l26.21,49.73L897,440.15C933.07,438.57,977,439.69,1031,443.55Z;M970.58,357.22s-2,28.38-8.85,67.39l43.5,20-48.47,5.71c-8,38-20.42,81.5-39.19,117.94l35.25,40.83-53-11.5a145,145,0,0,1-27,29c-21.47,17.06-48.81,28.09-79.24,36.16l-4.78,48.39-21.64-42.2c-26.65,5.54-54.9,9.63-83.11,14.06l-7.09,49.41-28.17-43.55c-33.17,6-65.31,13.47-93.68,25.51l7.82,48.1-31.74-36.25q-5.65,3.25-11,6.87c-30.39,20.57-45.74,45.61-55.8,73.75l27.09,21.69L456,834.88c-8.07,31.58-13.74,66.12-28.38,102.06l19.67,24.88-31.17-.19A269.7,269.7,0,0,1,374.27,1020c-1.74,1.86-3.51,3.68-5.32,5.44L380,1056.7l-28.75-16.44c-27.39,19.89-60.59,31.44-96.31,38.93l-2,37.09-18-33.34c-29.29,4.93-59.81,7.75-89.86,10.69l-5.87,42.67-20.08-40c-40.74,4.38-79.67,10.18-112.39,23.14l7.56,30.36-25.67-22.07c-16,8.46-30,19.24-41.41,33.22C-138.6,1266.4-120.81,1147-120.81,1147s.38-6.89,5.55-17.5a89.74,89.74,0,0,1,8.36-13.74,110.18,110.18,0,0,1,7-8.67c20.06-22.35,59.27-49.34,135.85-67.71q5-1.2,10.25-2.36L53,982.42l26.39,48.22c42.11-7,77-11.4,106.37-15.45l2.31-31.75,22.28,28.21c21.43-3.29,39.61-6.78,55.5-11.68l.28-34.27,17.55,27.72a123.08,123.08,0,0,0,40.71-28.32l-14.94-28.89,27.72,13.71c13.43-18,26.1-41.8,39.91-73.71q1.32-3,2.6-6.06l-24.26-20.58,33-.92c17.6-44.53,29.16-82.45,44.42-113.85l-26.07-34.71,39.57,10.52c24-37.12,59.34-62.69,129.12-76.89l6.43-50.32,25.67,44.92q7.75-1.05,16-2c28.77-3.21,54.58-4.36,78-5l19.56-52.51,18.33,51.66c27.34-.7,51-2,72.29-7.47l-1.33-55.38L844,600.2c25-14.29,47-39,68.59-82.05l-37.76-41.64,53.1,7.86C941.75,451,955.73,409.28,970.58,357.22Z"
                dur="1s"
                repeatCount="indefinite"
                fill="freeze"
                />
        </svg>
```

But sadly it does exactly the same as the js script I made.

(The thing I want to animate is something I drew on Illustrator and that I just miror with a SVG animation)

Comment: 1. Animations of `d` attributes only work if both paths have exactly the same sequence of commands: For every `c` in one path there must be a `c` in the other path, and not a `C`. 2. Try to make `<animate>` a child of the element you want to target. 3. `begin` should be `0s`, not `0`.

Comment: Is there a way to make those commands the same in illustrator?

Comment: AFAIK the optimization algorithm in Illustrator does not consider that aspect. I have no idea if it is possible to disable. If it doesnt work, you could try Inkscape. Try to edit the path once, so the formatting is triggered, and then save as **normal SVG**.

Comment: I just noticed you use `xlink:href` without declaring the namespace `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`. That might be another source of error.

Comment: @ccprog Firefox at least doesn't care about the case of commands. It does care about their overall number and that they are all the same ignoring case.

Comment: @RobertLongson good to know. Is the same true for repeating commands, i.e. L 1 2 3 4 vs L 1 2 L 3 4?